# How to add a function after a record inserted in database using django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools, django-admin-actions

I want to execute a function after a record inserted to database using django-admin panel .

I have a product table , i want to send notification to users when a record inserted in database by django admin panel . i know how to send notification to users , but i dont know where to put my code .

any suggestion will be helpfull .

How can i execute a function to notify user after my record inserted ?

here is my code to execute after record inserted :

```
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

device = FCMDevice.objects.all()

device.send_message(title="Title", body="Message", icon=..., data={"test": "test"})
```

i searched alot but not found anything usefull .

thanks to this great communtiy .

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/

Comment: I think this SO answer could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43146907/8583681

Comment: @Y.Bernard This is the answer i wanted , but the question is where to put the answer code ? i mean in admin.py or models.py , ....

Comment: @T.Pool models.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify save method on your product model

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    device = FCMDevice.objects.all()
    device.send_message(title="Title", body="Message", icon=..., data={"test": "test"})
```

Well, it will send the notification every time the instance is saved (not only when it was added in django admin panel).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Django model `post_save` signals to achieve this. This signal receiver can be placed in the same place where the model is

```
class FCMDevice(models.Model):
    ...

@receiver(post_save, sender=FCMDevice)
def notify_users(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     # your logic goes here
     # instance is referred to currently inserted row
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check `post_save` signal. From the docs:

> Like pre_save, but sent at the end of the save() method.

url: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save

django-version: 1.7+